# A way to get the column of a value in the first row/header of a sheet?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am trying something out in Google Spreadsheet with GAS,
Let's say I have a bunch of values in the the 1st row like so:

```
  |   A   |   B    |   C    |  D   |  E   |   F   |
1 | Apple | Orange | Banana | Pear | Lime | Melon |
```

What I would like then, is to have a function where you input a string like "Orange", and it would check which column "Orange" is in, and then output that column index. So with "Orange" it would return "B" as it is in column "B"/ Or just the index numeric "index".

Any suggestions?
or is more explanation needed?

Comment: dump the strings into an `array`, then use `indexOf` -- could use an alphabet string to get the column letter... `abcd...`

Comment: Sorry, I am not too sure on this, could you give an example? Would it be easier if I bring some context on the project?

Comment: Have you tried `HLOOKUP`? https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375

Comment: plenty of examples on the web: [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) &
[charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to programming - so there are probably better, more elegant and more efficient ways to do it, but this seems to work (thanks to WhiteHat for the hints)

```
function isInColumn(searchString) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DATA"); //insert your sheetname
  var columns = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPYRSTUVWXYZ"; // make a kind of index

  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:G"); // range is first row from A to G
  var values = range.getValues();

  var array = [];

  for (i in values[0]) 
     {
     array.push(values[0][i])   // values is a 2D array
     }    

  var indexNumber = array.indexOf(searchString); // get the position
  var column = columns.charAt(indexNumber);   // match this position to 'kind of index'
  return column;  

}
```

Search for "Orange" will return "B". Maybe you can go from here.